# Insert a field into joint-table doctrine

Tags: symfony, insert, doctrine, join

I want to insert into my joint-table RoleUser idUser  and idRole ,but in the function I should add an object user and role

How can I do that?

the joint table **RoleUser** :

```
/**
 * RoleUser 
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="role_user", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_role_user_id", columns={"ref_user_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_role_id", columns={"ref_role_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\RoleUserRepository")
 */
class RoleUser 
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Role
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Role")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ref_role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $refRole;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ref_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $refUser;  


      /**
         * @param Role $refRole
      */
     public function setRefRole(\AppBundle\Entity\Role $refRole)
     {
       $this->refRole = $refRole;
     }


     /**
      * @param User $refUser
      */
     public function setRefUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $refUser)
     {
        $this->refUser= $refUser;
     }



}
```

In my controller I want to insert the following (for a particular case I should insert in the background, the user can't choose his role):

```
 $user = new User();
 $role= new Role();
 $roleUser =new RoleUser();

 $roleUser->setRefUser($user->getId());
 $roleUser->setRefRole(1);
```

but I konw that I should pass a user and a role :

```
$roleUser->setRefUser($user);
 $roleUser->setRefRole($role);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a relation ManyToMany instead of OneToMany and remove your Entity RoleUser. you can follow the next [example](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional) in the documentation official, to mapping this kind of relations.

For the save:

In this case you need to add in the two entities this relation:

```php
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Location
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="location")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Location
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * <p>Represent the </p>
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="LogoLocation", mappedBy="locations")
     */
    private $logoLocationCurse;
    /**
     * Location constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->logoLocationCurse = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    public function addlogoLocationCurse(LogoLocation $location)
    {
        $this->logoLocationCurse->add($location);
        $location->addLocations($this);
    }
    public function removeLogo(LogoLocation $location)
    {
        $this->logoLocationCurse->removeElement($location);
        $location->removeLocation($this);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use \DateTime;

/**
 * Class LogoLocation
 * @ORM\Table(name="logo_location_curso")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class LogoLocation
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Many Users have Many Groups.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Location", inversedBy="logocurso")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="logo_locations")
     */
    private $locations;
    /**
     * LogoLocation constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->locations    = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    /**
     * @param Location $location
     */
    public function addLocations(Location $location)
    {
        $this->locations->add($location);
    }
    /**
     * @param Location $location
     */
    public function removeLocation(Location $location)
    {
        $this->locations->removeElement($location);
    }
    /**
     *
     */
    public function removeLocations()
    {
        /** @var Location $location */
        foreach ($this->locations as $location) {
            $location->removeLogo($this);
        }
    }
}
```

and make the flush